# retaining upload file information in form when validation fails on other fields

Tags: files, forms

If there are required fields in a form (ie '#required' is set to TRUE), and the user sets a file to be uploaded but not provide all the required fields, validation fails on the required fields and the validation hook does *not* get called; the specified file does not get uploaded (if that is where the upload code is placed) and the form is refreshed without the previously provided filename wiped out. Is there a way to either upload the file during validation, or reset the filename in the form field, so that the user doesn't have to reselect it again?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe using the [File_Managed fieldtype](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) will fix your problem. This Drupal FAPI field type uploads the file to a temp directory BEFORE the form is submitted, and so you can access the file during/after validation. You can see an example of it being applied in the "image_example.pages.inc" in the [Examples module](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples). Hope this helps.